# What happens exactly when setting spark.databricks.service.server.enabled to true on Databricks?

Tags: apache-spark, databricks

Can anyone explain what `spark.databricks.service.server.enabled` does exactly when it's set to true?
The only thing I can find in the documentation is that it should be set to true when using Databricks Runtime 5.3 or below, but I can't find an explanation of what's happening exactly under the hood (https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-connect.html)

I would be grateful for any helpful response.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note:** `spark.databricks.service.server.enabled true` helps you to work on a Databricks Cluster from a remote machine.

As part of cluster setup "`spark.databricks.service.server.enabled true`" helps Databricks Connect allows you to connect your favorite IDE (IntelliJ, Eclipse, PyCharm, RStudio, Visual Studio), notebook server (Zeppelin, Jupyter), and other custom applications to Azure Databricks clusters and run Apache Spark code.

Comment: Is there a way by which I can use dbutils in databricks notebook but the file that has that code is in python file and not a databricks notebook without setting this flag to true?